# Dojo DOH, unit tests with robot actions wont run

Tags: unit-testing, dojo, doh

When try to run dijit tests from 1.7 version, popup window shows up and test will not progress any further.

Popup says:

> DOH has detected that the current web page is attempting to access DOH, but belongs to a different domain than the one you agreed to let DOH automate. If you did not intend to start a new DOH test by visiting this Web page, press Cancel now and leave the Web page

Clicking OK or Cancel doesn't do anything.

Whats going on a how to fix this?

Browser is Firefox 9, java is working (at least test page say so).

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly hard to tell what the problem is, as you've not said whether you're running this from a local filesystem or under a web server, or which URL you're using.

I've had various problems trying to get DOH Robot running from the local filesystem, but good success running them under a web server.

Try it under a web server (any type will do), and try visiting the URL

```
http://server:port/ROOTDIR/util/doh/runner.html?testModule=dijit.tests.form.module
```

(where http://server:port/ROOTDIR/ points to the top of your Dojo SDK directory)

That works fine for me with Dojo SDK 1.7.2; sometimes I then get the same prompt you get, but OK enables the test to continue happily.

If that doesn't work, see if you can run a test page directly without the DOH browser runner wrapped around it, e.g.

```
http://server:port/ROOTDIR/dijit/tests/form/robot/Button_mouse.html
```

That might prove easier to diagnose.